# System.IO.IOException при создании папки

Tags: c#, windows, исключения, io

При попытке создать папку на C#, вылезает ошибка IOException:

> System.IO.IOException: "Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома. : 'G:\VISUALSTUDIO_PROJECTS\repos\DimucaTheDev\DimucaTheDev.M\DimucaTheDev.ExecutablePackage\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\AAAa
> '"

пробовал и `Directory.CreateDirectory("folder")`, и `new DirectoryInfo("folder").Create()`, ошибка все таже, в проводнике тот же самый путь открывает без каких либо проблем

Код:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string packageLocation = ".\\test.zip";
        StreamReader s = new(ZipFile.OpenRead(packageLocation).GetEntry("info").Open());
        string config = s.ReadToEnd();
        string output = "", exe = "";
        Dictionary<string, string> options = new();
       
        for (int i = 0; i < config.Split('\n').Length; i++)
        {
            var line = config.Split("\n")[i];
            if (line.StartsWith('#')) continue;
            if (line.StartsWith(' ')) continue;
            if (line.StartsWith("Output")) output = line.Split("=")[1];
            if (line.StartsWith("Start")) exe = line.Split("=")[1];
            if (line.StartsWith('@')) options.Add(line.Replace("@", ""), line);
        }
        s.Close();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(output);
        foreach (var item in options)
        {
            ZipFile.OpenRead(packageLocation).GetEntry($@"data\{item.Key}").ExtractToFile($"{Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(output),item.Value)}");
        }
        Process.Start(exe);
    }
```

Файл который надо прочитать:

```
    #This is example comment, lines starts with space will be skipped
    #This is out dir
    Output=AAAa
    @file1.png="FileNumberOne.png"
    Start="FileNumberOne.png"
```

Comment: Где-то какой-то символ лишний поставили, в дебаггере пройдитесь по строке которая у вас за путь отвечает, возможно там какой-нибудь `\n` затерялся

Comment: Пробел в конце действительно есть?

Comment: `StreamReader s =` файл открыли, прочитали, а закрыть забыли, читайте вот так `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);` прочитатся сразу разбитый по строкам, можно сразу в цикл эти строки закидывать.

Comment: А так, решение `output = line.Split("=")[1].Trim();`

Comment: Вообще с использованием Linq этот файл можно разобрать практически в одну строку `Dictionary<string, string> config = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => line.Trim()).Where(line => line.Length > 0 && !line.StartsWith("#")).Select(line => line.Split("=", 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());`. Словарик готов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в конце имени есть пробел, то windows не сможет корректно работать с таким каталогом.

Удалить через интерфейс его тоже не получиться, только через командную строку  или удалением родительского каталога.